# Laravel how to load uploaded images on webhost

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

After successfully loading my laravel project to infinityfree I noticed each time I tried to upload a image file it would show a broken link. I tried using the symlink command but I learned that due to "security" reasons the free web hosting service blocks linked folders. I found a work around that lets me upload the files to the "public/storage" directory but for some reason the images still won't show. Everything works perfectly with localhost. Any idea on how I can fix this issue without having to pay extra?

here's the code

in the "config/filesystems.php" file change

```
‘local’ => [
‘driver’ => ‘local’,
‘root’ => storage_path(‘app’),
],
‘public’ => [
‘driver’ => ‘local’,
‘root’ => storage_path(‘app/public’),
‘url’ => env(‘APP_URL’) . ‘/storage’,
‘visibility’ => ‘public’,
],
```

to this

```
‘local’ => [
‘driver’ => ‘local’,
‘root’ => public_path(‘storage’),
],
‘public’ => [
‘driver’ => ‘local’,
‘root’ => public_path(‘storage’),
‘url’ => env(‘APP_URL’) . ‘/storage’,
‘visibility’ => ‘public’,
],
```

all uploaded images now appear in the "app/public/storage/public/cover_images" directory.

the link I'm using to load them with is

```
src="/storage/cover_images/{{ $latestproduct->cover_image }}"
```

Comment: Did you forgot to run `php artisan storage:link`?

Comment: yes it says that the link already exists but Im still having the problem.

Comment: Try using  `storage_path('/cover_images/....')`

Comment: @tithira which line of code am I replacing this with?

Comment: Is the `public/storage` a folder or a symlink? If it's a folder, rename of remove it, and run the link command again.

Comment: @daantje tried it and its still not working. on my machine it shows that the storage file is a symlink but in the ftp file manager they don't seem to be linked. i can see that the images aren't moving/uploading to the directory.

Comment: Are you running the command on the remote machine? Or are you running it local and then uploading it with FTP? Because that is not working. You'll have to run the command on the remote machine, or change the storage path's in your config.